# BackPack CRUD Select Title But Save ID

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

Here is an example of what I am trying to do (I have PRO version and DevTools incase anyone needed to know):
Lets say I have a CRUD setup for People.
In the List I have the School the Person is assigned to.

In the People CRUD I want to be able to Search for a "Name" of the School the person goes to but when selected and saved the CRUD will just store the School ID associated so its a relation.

Then on the list view it will showcase the School Name but again in the database only stores the ID and goes and fetches the Name. I am sure this is really easy to do but I cannot seem to find documentation on this as an example.

I have checked the docs and good as best as I can but not been able to find any documentation on it so any info or links would be great!

Answer (score 0):

In your `People` model you should have the relationship setup like:

```php
public function school()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\YourSchoolModel', 'school_id');
}
```

So you should define your columns like:

```php
    public function setupListOperation()
    {
        $this->crud->addColumn([  
            'name'      => 'school',
            'searchLogic' => function ($query, $column, $searchTerm) {
                $possibleSchools = SchoolModel::where('school_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')->pluck('id');
                return $query->orWhereIn('school_id', $possibleSchools);
            },
        ]);
```

You can check other examples here: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-columns#custom-order-logic-for-columns

Cheers

Comment: Ok I will take a look and see if thats doing what I want thank you.